# "Combining" two branches in git. Solving the merge conflict

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Say I have a file called `README.md`. On the first commit to `master` it looks like this:

```
1 line 1
2
3
4
5
```

After that commit I make a new branch called `branch1`. I make some changes and commit this to that branch:

```
1 line 1
2
3 line 3
4
5
```

I then switch back to `master` and make one final change to `README.md`:

```
1 line 1
2 line 2
3
4
5
```

I then attempt to merge `branch1` into `master` but get a merge conflict:

```
line 1
+<<<<<<< destination:cc7a08f60b9dffc80ccdbdc4c0d74b1c89ef3a0d
line 2
+=======
+
+line 3
+>>>>>>> source:715105a18fc54b681cb451492bfe07bb49305a2e
```

Why can't the `branch1` and `master` branch simply be merged into something that looks like this?:

```
1 line 1
2 line 2
3 line 3
4
5
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Because automerges that accept changes so close to each other without human intervention have an unacceptably bad track record.

Comment: This question elucidates how git processes conflicts. It may help you understand it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920885/what-constitutes-a-merge-conflict-in-git