# Managing Android project using Git and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I believe I have a very common problem that affects developers with multiple versions of their apps (in my case I have two: paid one and a free one).
To manage both versions I use the same git project with 2 different branches: free and paid
However my source code package names differ from each other (as expected), and with the java restrictions of having the directory names mapping to package names a problem arises: how to  tell git to associate the files under a certain directory with each branch ?

Let me give you an example:
I've two branches:

1. master
2. free

In master my source code is under com.zemariamm, however in the "free" branch the source code is under "com.zemariamm.free", how can I configure git to "tell him" that the source code under directory com.zemariamm (in branch master) maps to the source code under directory com.zemariamm.free (in branch free) ?

Thanks so much in advance,
Ze

Comment: Can't you just share all the common code libraries, rather than having duplicates in the `free` and `paid` packages?

Comment: What do you mean? Having two different projects using parts of the source code ? Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you wouldn't configure anything in Git:
If the *content* of `com.zemariamm.free.MyClass` is very similar to `com.zemariamm.MyClass`, Git should be able to link the history of the `MyClass` file between the two directories in the two different branches.

In particular, a merge from `free` to `master` should report new evolutions (lines added, modified or removed to `MyClass`) from the `com.zemariamm.free.MyClass` to the `com.zemariamm.MyClass`.

That only works if `MyClass` is "similar enough between the two branches though:
see "[**How does Git track history during a refactoring ?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520023/how-does-git-track-history-during-a-refactoring/3520055#3520055)"

Answer (score 0):

Why not put just put both the free and paid code in one project, rather than using two projects?