# How to make github follow directory history after renames?

Tags: github

Once a directory is renamed, "git log" no longer shows its history, unless you force it to, by using "git log --follow".

Is there a way to force the "history" function on the GitHub web UI to use "--follow"?

Alternatively - is there *any* way to see pre-rename history on GitHub?

Comment: I've opened a GitHub ticket, and got the following reply "There isn't currently.  This is a known issue, I have a ticket open to get it fixed."

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Update June 2022: GitHub now supports [viewing commit history across file renames and moves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72521525/6309)!

[image: View commit history across file renames and moves].

---

2011: This was requested in 2009 ([Request 129](http://support.github.com/discussions/feature-requests/129-history)), and then in 2010 ([Request 897](http://support.github.com/discussions/feature-requests/897-make-file-history-follow-renames)), and then in 2021 (`github/feedback` discussion 6964):

> I like this.
> There could be other issues preventing us from plopping the `--follow` argument in.
> I'll take a look and let you know.

... and then nothing for now.

---

Note: Git 2.6+  (Q3 2015) will propose that in command line: see "[Why does git log not default to `git log --follow`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32039661/6309)"

---

Note: Git 2.6.0 has been released and includes this feature. Following path changes in the log command can be enabled by setting the log.follow config option to true as in:

```
git config log.follow true
```

Comment: These links both go to https://github.com/contact . I can't see requests themselves.

Comment: @PhilipDurbin yes, GitHub has since removed its discussion section

Comment: thanks, is there any public tracking of this feature request?

Comment: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/6964

Comment: @BriandeAlwis Thank you. I have added this reference to the list of issues/discussions requesting this feature in my answer.

Answer (score 19):

I wrote a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-follow/agalokjhnhheienloigiaoohgmjdpned) to enable this.  [Source](https://github.com/staff0rd/github-follow-extension) on github.

[image: Github Follow Extension]

Comment: Interesting. +1, nice workaround to [my own answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5647721/6309).

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe GitHub redesigned the UI and this doesn't appear to be working anymore

Answer (score 17):

I've sent a mail to support@github.com (salutations removed):

> Will "git --follow" functionality ever be implemented on Github? If yes, where can I track its progress?
>
> (By "git --follow", I mean a way to *easily* see the object revisions before a rename. Currently, when an item is renamed, Github doesn't offer an easy way to display the directory / file history.)

Response:

> > Will "git --follow" functionality ever be implemented on Github? If yes,
>   where can I track its progress?
>
> This is something a few other users have requested as well -- we might add it in the future. We currently don't have a public issue tracker, but I'll put another +1 next to it on the Feature Request List™ for the team to see.

So, "git --follow" is unfortunately not supported yet.

To get such functionality in the meantime, I guess you could write a user script that looks up the hash of the parent object, (recursively) look up its history and render the result.

Comment: Interesting feedback, which confirms my answer. +1. Next question for GitHub: where is this "Feature Request List" for the users to vote on? ;)

Comment: Another update: *"Thanks for getting in touch. This hasn't been shipped, however we definitely appreciate the feedback. I'll add a +1 to this item on our internal Feature Request List, however I can't make any promises if/when this might be available."*

Comment: Another option is to setup project mirror (or just migrate there) on GitLab and preview history there. GitLab does support that.