# git combining two files into one with history preserved

Tags: git, file, merge

Imagine that you have two files in a git repository, say `A.txt` and `B.txt`.

Is it possible to concat the two files into a third one `A+B.txt`, removing the original `A.txt` and `B.txt` and committing it all, so the history is still preserved?

That is, if I asked `git log --follow A+B.txt` I would know that the content originated from the `A.txt` and `B.txt` files?

I've tried to separate the files into two different branches and then merging them into a new file (while removing the old ones), but to no avail.

Comment: you can try renaming `A.txt` to `A+B.txt`, add in the changes from `B.txt` and delete `B.txt`, then commiting that.

Comment: Why not put that in the commit message when you make A+B.txt that it is concat of A.txt and B.txt.

Comment: Reverse operation - [Preserving Git history while splitting file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3887736)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The long answer is 'yes'!

Full credit to Raymond Chen's article [**Combining two files into one while preserving line history**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190514-00/?p=102493):

Imagine you had two files: `fruits` & `veggies`

[image: git blame for both fruits and veggies]

> The naïve way of combining the files would be to do it in a single commit, but you'll lose line history on one of the files (or both)
>
> You could tweak the `git blame` algorithms with options like `-M` and `-C` to get it to try harder, but in practice, you don’t often have control over those options (eg. the git blame may be performed on a server)
>
> #### The trick is to use a `merge` with two forked branches
>
> - In one branch, we rename `veggies` to `produce`.
> - In the other branch, we rename `fruits` to `produce`.
>
> ```sh
> git checkout -b rename-veggies
> git mv veggies produce
> git commit -m "rename veggies to produce"
> ```
>
> ```sh
> git checkout -
> git mv fruits produce
> git commit -m "rename fruits to produce"
> ```
>
> Then merge the first into the second
>
> ```sh
> git merge -m "combine fruits and veggies" rename-veggies
> ```
>
> This will generate a merge conflict - that's okay - now take the changes from each branch's Produce file and combine into one - here's a simple concatenation (but resolve the merge conflict however you please):
>
> ```sh
> cat "produce~HEAD" "produce~rename-veggies" >produce
> git add produce
> git merge --continue
> ```
>
> ***The resulting `produce` file was created by a merge, so git knows to look in both parents of the merge to learn what happened.***
>
> [image: git blame for produce]
>
> And that’s where it sees that each parent contributed half of the file, and it also sees that the files in each branch were themselves created via renames of other files, so it can chase the history back into both of the original files.
>
> Each line should be correctly attributed to the person who introduced it in the original file, whether it’s fruits or veggies. People investigating the produce file get a more accurate history of who last touched each line of the file.
>
> For best results, your rename commit should be a pure rename. Resist the temptation to edit the file’s contents at the same time you rename it. A pure rename ensure that git’s rename detection will find the match. If you edit the file in the same commit as the rename, then whether the rename is detected as such will depend on git’s “similar files” heuristic.

Checkout [the full article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190514-00/?p=102493) for a full step by step breakdown and more explanations

---

Originally, I had thought this might be [a use case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9862173/1366033) for [`git merge-file`](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-merge-file.html) doing something like this:

```sh
>produce echo #empty
git merge-file fruits produce veggies --union -p > produce
git rm fruits veggies
git add produce
git commit -m "combine fruits and veggies"
```

However, all this does is help simulate the merge diffing algorithm against two different files - the end output when committed is identical to if the file had been updated manually and the resulting changes manually committed

Comment: Combine both files in each branch so the merge has no conflicts. Otherwise rebasing revives the conflict every time.

Comment: That's awesome! But how would you go about merging file A into file B, without renaming file B? Do I first have to rename the target file to something else in a separate commit? Or is there a nicer way to do it?

Comment: @Hubro, the trick is you have to rename both A & B, that way they both get to be considered parents, and there's no single winner.

Comment: To see full line history, e. g. after splitting + rejoining a file, use `git blame -C40`. To put that in effect in TortoiseGitBlame Window, this can be set up with "Detect moved or copied lines" = "From modified files".

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is "no" (or perhaps even [Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative))).  (But for a way to get useful synthesized *line* history *for* a combined file via `git blame`, see [KyleMit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58702049/1256452).)

History, in Git, *is* the set of commits.  There is no such thing as "file history": you either have a commit, or you don't, and that commit has one or more parents, or it doesn't.  This means that "file history" as a thing doesn't exist—and yet, `git log --follow` exists.  This is self-contradictory:  How can `git log --follow` produce a file history, if file history doesn't exist?

The answer is that `git log --follow` cheats.  It doesn't really find file history.  It looks through history and *constructs a sub-history* by changing the (single) name of the file it is looking for.  It looks at each commit, one at a time, and runs a (sped-up, limited) `git diff --find-renames` of that commit against its parent.<sup>1</sup>  If the diff says that file `X.txt` in the parent was renamed to `A.txt` in the child, and you're running `git log --follow A.txt`, the code in `git log` now starts looking for `X.txt`.

Since there's no code to start looking for more than one file at a time, you can't get this particular cheat to accommodate your desired situation, which is to go from looking for one particular file to more-than-one file.  (There are actually two problems here.  One is that, due to the rather limited internal implementation,<sup>2</sup> `git log --follow` can only look at one file at a time.  The other is that rename detection does not include "combine detection": there is a form of "split detection", in which Git will do copy-finding, enabled with `--find-copies` and `--find-copies-harder`.  The latter is very compute-intensive, and both are working in the wrong direction here, although it could be made to do the right thing simply by reversing the order of the diff.)

---

<sup>1</sup>As this implies, `--follow` doesn't look at merge diffs at all, at least by default.  See also [`git log --follow --graph` skips commits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46487476/1256452).

<sup>2</sup>aka "cheesy hack"

Comment: looks like one vehicle is to create identical file names and merge from one branch into another so git will make an attempt to look at the merged parents when assigning line by line attribution (see below)

Comment: @KyleMit: that *is* a nice hack. It doesn't make the one file have two file histories—there's still no real *file* history at all, and `git log` won't help you here. But it does make `git blame` on the merge commit, and commits that follow it, much more useful. The blame (or annotate) command is synthesizing *line* history from *commit* history, and this makes it do a much better job of it.

Answer (score 0):

The [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190514-00/?p=102493) by Raymond Chen and cited by [KyleMit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58702049/1256452) is the best answer.  Below is a solution that ultimately only keeps half of the line history, but I'm going to leave it up for reference/education.

Instead of merging the branches, just use `cherry-pick` to pull in the commit.  This will still cause a conflict to be resolved, but the result will be a single commit without a merge commit, and a simpler history for future operations (at the cost of one file's line history).

```
git checkout -b temp
git mv A.txt AB.txt
git commit -am "moving B to AB"
git switch main
git mv B.txt AB.txt
git commit -am "moving A to AB"
git cherry-pick temp
```

resolve the conflict

```
git add AB.txt
git cherry-pick --continue
```

AB.txt will preserve the blame history

```
git blame AB.txt
```