# See history in GitHub after folder rename

Tags: git, github, revision-history

After renaming a folder (`git mv foldername newfoldername`) the history of this folder in Github has gone. I can still view the full history of any file in the folder if I clone the repro and run...

```
git log --follow ./newfoldername/file
```

But is it possible to get history for renamed folders visible in Github? 
This is a Github question, the git revision history is working as expected. 
Thanks

Comment: Since it doesn't pertain to Git per se, I changed the title. Also, file/dir-level history isn't really *tracked* in Git, it's rather *reconstructed*. If GitHub could do this reconstruction the way you wanted, you'd probably have seen it already.

Comment: Note that Git does not explicitly track renames of files (a renamed file results in its old entry missing from the next tree object representing that file's directory, and the new entry added to it), and renaming of a directory results just to the single change to an appropriate entry to a tree object representing the state of an enclosing directory. As @larsmans correctly points out, renames are *guessed* by the `git log` machinery (which has several knobs to affect this). So I'd not hold my breath to have a proper solution to your problem.

Comment: Note also that `git` doesn't track history for folders at all, beyond the notion of "this file lives in this folder in this particular tree/commit"...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make github follow directory history after renames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646174/how-to-make-github-follow-directory-history-after-renames)

Answer (score 16):

### Edit

This extension is no longer needed as [this answer shows GitHub now implements this functionality natively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72521525/469777)

### Previous

I wrote a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-follow/agalokjhnhheienloigiaoohgmjdpned) to enable this.  [Source](https://github.com/staff0rd/github-follow-extension) on github.

[image: Github Follow Extension]

Comment: Bit of an older thread, but are you maintaining this? Because it doesn't seem to work currently :( Here's a commit with a few moves: https://github.com/Rene-Sackers/gta-network-typescript/commit/f61486b6b456830c8ea3f648c325fb26186326ea

Comment: You need to be looking at the history of a file rather than a commit, e.g: https://github.com/Rene-Sackers/gta-network-typescript/commits/f61486b6b456830c8ea3f648c325fb26186326ea/content/types-gtanetwork/Declarations.d.ts

Comment: Why on EARTH is this something that needs a _browser extension_ ?!?

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, apparently: https://github.com/Rene-Sackers/gta-network-typescript/commits/master/content/types-gtanetwork/NativeUI.dll.d.ts

Comment: @DorianMarchal I still see it: https://imgur.com/a/tHkeWQ9.  If you don't see that, open an issue and I'll have a look - https://github.com/staff0rd/github-follow-extension/issues

Answer (score 11):

You just need a commit before the rename happened. You could retrieve it locally or via the Blame feature.

After you have retrieved the URL of such commit you just need to click History. You will then see all of the commit history of the file before the rename.

Comment: is there any way to do this in the API level, either in `REST` or in `Graphql`

Answer (score 2):

This is now (June 2022, 9 years later) supported by GitHub:

> ### [View commit history across file renames and moves](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-06-06-view-commit-history-across-file-renames-and-moves/)
>
> When a file is renamed or moved to a new directory but half of it's contents remain the same, it's commit history will now indicate that the file was renamed, similar to [`git log --follow`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---follow).
>
> [image: View commit history across file renames and moves]