# Why the commits shown in blame view is not in the history view of the same file in github

Tags: git, github

Here is one problematic [file](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/blob/master/components/org.wso2.analytics.apim/pom.xml) I found. When the blame view is clicked this [page](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/blame/master/components/org.wso2.analytics.apim/pom.xml) is given, when I take a look in to the [history](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/commits/master/components/org.wso2.analytics.apim/pom.xml) of the same file, it does not contain all the commits as shown in the blame view for the same file. For example the commit `ce1b694d4a06425f933dfee5e0966349fdb9581d` which added the lines from 40 to 52 is not shown in  the history of the same file. What is the reason for this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earliest commit shown in the file's history was a refactoring, during which the file was moved.  The commit you see in the `blame` output is from before the file moved.

The history will have been generated using a command like `git log -- /components/org.wso2.analytics.apim/pom.xml`, which doesn't follow file moves.

You can tell git (at the command line) to provide a history that *does* follow file moves by saying `git log --follow -- /components/org.wso2.analytics.apim/pom.xml`, which I've verified does show the ce1b69 commit.

(As an aside, by default `git log` also presents a simplified history.  I can't think of an obvious reason why this would omit a commit that shows up in `blame`, but if two branches both introduced the same range of lines I would suppose it could be possible.  Adding `--full-history` to the log would remedy that, if ever you were to encounter it.)

Comment: Note that support for viewing more complete history on the github site isn't all you might hope for... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213046/see-history-in-github-after-folder-rename