# Why GitHub doesn't display the file history when the commit history does?

Tags: git, github, git-revert, git-rewrite-history

I've recently found a strange behaviour about GitHub repository.

When I choose file and then its history (because I want to see all changes/commits to this file) there is only one - last commit: [`beans/AuthenticationBean.java`](https://github.com/MarianMacik/Kartoteka/commits/master/src/main/java/cz/muni/fi/macik/kartoteka/beans/AuthenticationBean.java).

But when I check all the commits to the whole repository (main page with folder structure where language statistics are present, number of commits and so on) I can find 5 commits which contain changes to this file, as [this commit](https://github.com/MarianMacik/Kartoteka/commit/2787506425ee23adf6dfc7f0b7b2d9d446a61c8a).

I don't know if it has something to do with one revert I made throughout the project.
I've read somewhere that revert may cause something like history reset.
But I would be pleased if you can help or explain this situation to me.

Comment: Can you share the url of that repo and that file within that repo?

Comment: https://github.com/MarianMacik/Kartoteka   - repo and https://github.com/MarianMacik/Kartoteka/blob/master/src/main/java/cz/muni/fi/macik/kartoteka/beans/AuthenticationBean.java - file - there is only one version through file history, but file is already present in commit https://github.com/MarianMacik/Kartoteka/commit/2787506425ee23adf6dfc7f0b7b2d9d446a61c8a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is:
[`src/main/java/cz/muni/fi/macik/kartoteka/beans/AuthenticationBean.java`](https://github.com/MarianMacik/Kartoteka/blob/master/src/main/java/cz/muni/fi/macik/kartoteka/beans/AuthenticationBean.java)

The other is:
[`src/main/java/cz/muni/fi/pv168/kartoteka/AuthenticationBean.java`](https://github.com/MarianMacik/Kartoteka/blob/2787506425ee23adf6dfc7f0b7b2d9d446a61c8a/src/main/java/cz/muni/fi/pv168/kartoteka/AuthenticationBean.java)

That means that file have moved, and GitHub doesn't support a `git log --follow`, as confirmed in February 2014 by GitHub support: see "[github follow history by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21508105/6309)".

That is why the history of the file is limited to the commits done after the move.

Comment: Thanks! I have forgotten that I was doing file reorganization. ;)