# How to move a file (while preserving the history) and create one with the same name in git?

Tags: git

I have the following problem: I have a git repo and I want to move the file x.y from directory A to directory B while preserving its history. Then I want to create a new file with the same name (x.y) but a different content in directory A.

I have tryed this using `git mv A/x.y B/x.y` and then creating a new file x.y in A. But it didn't work the way I wanted to. My git log shows that the file `B/x.y` was created new (and has no history) and that the old content of file `A/x.y` was removed and the new content was added (this file still has all the history, where it should have none)

So my question to the git gurus is: Is this possible and how do I do it? Is there maybe a parameter for `git add` that I can use or something while creating the file?

Comment: Unfortunately git moved files detection & handling isn't that good, which is why you notice things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `git log --follow -- b/x.y`: you should see the log history of `x.y` even before the move.

```
--follow
```

> Continue listing the history of a file beyond renames (works only for a single file).

If you wanted to *not* use `--follow`, [you would need git filter-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15135004/6309).

However, that won't be [visible on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5647721/6309) (nor BitBucket).

Comment: Ok I see. But it doesn't show up that way on Github... edit: using `git log --follow`

Comment: @Foaly `git log` is you doing something on your local machine, it doesn't affect github. Github would need to use the command/implement a similar system in their view for it to be able.

Comment: @dtech I think the OP means that, once pushed to GitHub, the extended history (with --follow) would no longer be visible.