# gitk equivalent of git log --follow <full path to file>

Tags: git, gitk, source-control-explorer

So I have a file called `one.txt` that I have been modifying over the years on master branch.  `gitk one.txt` will show the entire history of that one particular file.  However after I changed `one.txt` => `two.txt`, `gitk two.txt` doesn't show any change before the rename.

I tried `gitk --follow two.txt`, but only gave the comment for each commit, but not the actual file change information.

I know I can do `git log --follow two.txt`, but you have to `gitk` each SHA1 value to each what is being changed.

So any tips?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25090142/549246 ... I wrote a little one-liner that'll do what you want.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is [`gitk --follow` will for now differ from `git log --follow`](http://66.135.57.166/lists/git/msg142677.html), considering, according to Linux Torvalds, `--follow` is mainly a hack:

> I'm pretty sure I mentioned about this exact issue when I posted the original follow patches, and it basically boils down to: "`--follow`" is a total hack, and does *not* use the regular commit filtering function, and as a result, fancy things like "`--parent`" don't really work well with it.
>
> IOW, I'm not at all certain that it is fixable. "`--follow` is a very fundamentally non-gitty thing to do, and really is a complete hack. It's a fairly *small* hack - if you didn't know better and looked at the source code, you might think that it fits very naturally into git. But no.
>
> Now, it's possible that we could hack up `--parent` to work with `--follow` too, but quite frankly, I don't know how. Because the `--follow` hack really basically boils down to:
>
> - do *not* prune commits at all (this the the thing that normally simplifies the parenthood and removes uninteresting commits)
> - for the whole list of normal commits in "`git log`", do the patch generation with a magic special hack that looks for renames.
> - if it was a rename, change the path that we magically track, so that the next commit that we look at, we'll follow the new (older) path.
> - if the patch is empty, we force-hide the commit (internally, this is the "`rev->always_show_header = 0;`" thing)
>
> and the key here is that we do all the magic at the *end* of the queue, long after we've done the pruning of commits that normally does the parenthood renaming.
>
> Sorry. I have used `--follow` occasionally, but it's a hack to see "ok, there it got renamed". It would be nice if "`gitk --follow <pathname>`" worked properly, but it's just not something I care very much about.

---

Another difference, the support of pathspec magic: Before Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), "`git [-c log.follow=true] log [--follow] ':(glob)f**'`" used to barf.

See [commit 8260bc5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8260bc59023136edeaed1f1006a03f44cc849883), [commit 9eac595](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9eac5954e81037f282ace2efff7110af3440dc19), [commit 8e32caa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e32caaa783a3a6b1d94834ee6e2d21ac36ff39f) (01 Jun 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit de00f4b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de00f4b7f3fd3aca18e4bea286bf060c595efd3b), 20 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8260bc59023136edeaed1f1006a03f44cc849883): detect pathspec magic not supported by `--follow`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Jim Pryor</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The `--follow` code doesn't handle most forms of pathspec magic.
> We check that no unexpected ones have made it to `try_to_follow_renames()` with a runtime `GUARD_PATHSPEC()` check, which gives behavior like this:
>
> ```
> $ git log --follow ':(icase)makefile' >/dev/null
> BUG: tree-diff.c:596: unsupported magic 10
> Aborted
> ```
>
> The same is true of "`:(glob)`", "`:(attr)`", and so on.
> It's good that we notice the problem rather than continuing and producing a wrong answer.
> But there are two non-ideal things:
>
> 1. The idea of `GUARD_PATHSPEC()` is to catch programming errors where low-level code gets unexpected pathspecs.
>    We'd usually try to catch unsupported pathspecs by passing a `magic_mask` to `parse_pathspec()`, which would give the user a much better message like:
>
>    ```
>    pathspec magic not supported by this command: 'icase'
>    ```
>
>    That doesn't happen here because git-log usually *does* support
>    all types of pathspec magic, and so it passes "0" for the mask
>    (this call actually happens in setup_revisions()). It needs to
>    distinguish the normal case from the "--follow" one but currently
>    doesn't.
> 2. In addition to `--follow`, we have the `log.follow` config option.
>    When that is set, we try to turn on `--follow` mode only when there is a single pathspec (since `--follow` doesn't handle anything else).
>    But really, that ought to be expanded to "use `--follow` when the pathspec supports it".
>    Otherwise, we'd complain any time you use an exotic pathspec:
>
>    ```
>    $ git config log.follow true
>    $ git log ':(icase)makefile' >/dev/null
>    BUG: tree-diff.c:596: unsupported magic 10
>    Aborted
>    ```
>
>    We should instead just avoid enabling follow mode if it's not
>    supported by this particular invocation.
>
> This patch expands our `diff_check_follow_pathspec()` function to cover pathspec magic, solving both problems.

Comment: Sigh...always the git he is.  He should care about this >.<

Comment: I suppose there are no updates for this... @qin have you at least tried Git Extensions? Its `--follow` seem to work fine.

Comment: @Cawas no evolution that I can see in the logs of git (https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes).

Comment: I'm almost opening a new question, Von... This was so far the closest I got to why `--follow` isn't properly following a file, on `git` (not gitk). Binary file, if that matters. Would you have any pointers on that? :P

Comment: @Cawas no pointer right now, but consider `--follow` is based on a diff mechanism (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520023/how-does-git-track-history-during-a-refactoring/3520055#3520055), which I doubt is working for binaries (using "binary diff": http://stackoverflow.com/a/4705537/6309) .

Comment: @Cawas: Even the diff stats aren't ideal for binaries: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=141917

Comment: I think I've found the google groups with the quote you brought from Linus, also very insightful on the issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/git-version-control/07oWjHiQTtg

Comment: @Cawas sure, it was also from http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/147037/focus=147089

Comment: Just wanted to note, in light of the Linus excerpt, that --follow *sometimes* does the right thing, even if not with gitk. In the thread VonC and Cawas found ("Git log follow question") Linus says "'git log --follow' works fine. As does 'git blame -C'." But "git log" does not *always* do what you'd hope either: "fancy things like '--parent' don't really work well with it."

Comment: This is the primary stopper to refactoring of project structure. The nearest native workaround on gitk is to filter commits using file mask (and storing it as a view), ofc this is useless for commits beyond a simple file move (e.g. abc renamed to xyz)