# Viewing Git history of moved files

Tags: git

Despite reading lots of other posts regarding GIT and moved files I still struggle to understand how to trace the full history.  Doing `gitk myfile` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/git-how-do-i-view-the-change-history-of-a-file) seems to only show history until the previous move.  I understand that GIT doesn't track files, only their content.  So surely I should be able to view the full evolution of a file, even if it's been moved?

Can anyone direct me to a good yet simple example/tutorial?

I'd like to see an example where some files are moved around, changed and committed, then the history of a single file is displayed, moves and all.  I've been looking at 'log' but that seems to concern checkins.  Would still appreciate some advice, even if its says I'm somehow still thinking too much SVN.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430749/getting-git-to-acknowledge-previously-moved-files and http://gitster.livejournal.com/35628.html

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Try using the [`--follow` option to `git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log --follow file.txt
```

Comment: Note that currently the `--follow` mechanism is bolted-on, and doesn't work in some corner-cases.

Comment: If you get `fatal: ambiguous argument 'file.txt': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`, try git log --follow -- file.txt

Comment: @nealmcb adding the ```--```  before the path/to/file was exactly what was missing. Worked great after adding that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use `git log` with both `--follow` and `--patch` which will display the log with the rename from / rename to output.  And don't forget the `--` before the file path.

```
git log --follow --patch -- path/to/file.ext
```

For example the history of file `testdir/more-testing.txt` on my system shows:

> ```
> Date:   Wed Mar 18 14:48:07 2020 -0700
>
>    renamed file
>
> diff --git a/testdir/testing.txt b/testdir/more-testing.txt
> similarity index 100%
> rename from testdir/testing.txt
> rename to testdir/more-testing.txt
>
> commit feb58d3ab8e8ce940f80499df0c46e8fc8caf679
> Author: Igal <redacted>
> Date:   Wed Mar 18 14:47:18 2020 -0700
>
>    moved test.txt to subdirectory and renamed
>
> diff --git a/test.txt b/testdir/testing.txt
> similarity index 100%
> rename from test.txt
> rename to testdir/testing.txt
>
> commit 34c4a7cebaeb0df5afb950972d69adea6b1a7560
> Author: Igal <redacted>
> Date:   Wed Mar 18 14:45:58 2020 -0700
>
>    added test.txt
>
> diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
> new file mode 100644
> index 000000000..0527e6bd2
> --- /dev/null
> +++ b/test.txt
> @@ -0,0 +1 @@
> +This is a test
> (END)
> ```