# How to find a deleted file in the project commit history?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Once upon a time, there was a file in my project that I would now like to be able to get.

The problem is: I have no idea of when have I deleted it and on which path it was.

How can I locate the commits of this file when it existed?

Answer (score 2337, accepted):

If you do not know the exact path you may use

```
git log --all --full-history -- "**/thefile.*"
```

If you know the path the file was at, you can do this:

```
git log --all --full-history -- <path-to-file>
```

This should show a list of commits in all branches which touched that file. Then, you can find the version of the file you want, and display it with...

```
git show <SHA> -- <path-to-file>
```

Or restore it into your working copy with:

`git checkout <SHA>^ -- <path-to-file>`

Note the caret symbol (`^`), which gets the checkout *prior* to the one identified, because at the moment of `<SHA>` commit the file is deleted, we need to look at the previous commit to get the deleted file's contents

Comment: Try using a relative path instead of an absolute one (if you aren't already).

Comment: What if you don't know the exact path? All you know is the filename?

Comment: @priestc Answered in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845234/viewing-git-history-of-moved-files)

Comment: @priestc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017987/is-there-a-way-in-git-to-list-all-deleted-files-in-the-repository

Comment: side note : your path must use '/' and not '\' took me a whole day to figure it out :/

Comment: @PedroMorteRolo `git log -- <path>` will have no output when you are on a branch in which the file never existed. You should always use `git log --all -- <path>`, to make sure you don't miss changes that happened on other branches. The command `git log -- <path>` can be very dangerous if you have more than one branch and tend to forget paths and branches (like me) and it's also dangerous if you work with other developers.

Comment: @Amber, consider adding `--all` (thanks [Philip](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7204977/623735)) to your `git log` answer, so that people don't miss changes and files on other branches. It would save forgetful people like me a lot of grief.

Comment: As stated in the answer below, restoring the file should be `git checkout <SHA>^ -- <path-to-file>` (note the ^ symbol), because at the moment of <SHA> commit the file is deleted, we need to look at the previous commit to get the deleted file's contents

Comment: @kipelovets that assumes you're using the sha of the delete commit, rather than the sha of the version of the file you wanted.

Comment: @kipelovets I don't see why `^` would be necessary. Why would you choose the hash after the last one that has the file?

Comment: When using `**/thefile.*` it's usually a good idea to quote it, e.g., `'**/thefile.*'`, to protect the glob `*` from the shell. (I'm not familiar with WIndows shells and when they eat `*`s, but if there's an accidental match from the current working directory in bash, that could make trouble.)

Comment: This did not work for me, the command returns nothing, but [second most voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21871377/284111) worked.

Comment: I ran the command `git log --all -- <path/to/file>` which does give me some history of the file: when the file is added and changed. But it doesn't show the commit when the file is moved or deleted.  any cases which are not covered in the discussion above?

Comment: Make sure your change directory to the root of the git projects. I had problems with the relative path when using the commands from a sub directory

Comment: filename is case sensitive. Good to know for windows users where cmds usually aren't.

Comment: Doesn't work in git 2.7.4 + fish shell. The alternative answer by Calaf if you have this combination.

Comment: When I run the first cmd it list commits that has nothing to do with the deleted file

Comment: add `--stat` to your `git log` command to actually see the files modded in the returned commits.

Comment: `git log --all --  <FILE-PATH>` is enough for my case to find deleted file

Comment: @jonS90 I'm not sure what shell you use, but neither bash nor zsh will expand wildcards inside double quotes.

Comment: @Amber you're right. Whatever I thought I saw I can't reproduce. I'm going to delete that comment.

Comment: Why is the caret not needed for `show`? I want to be 'show'n the file before the delete.

Comment: Curious, why `git log <SHA>^ -- <path-to-file>` return error. But if I do `git checkout <SHA>^` as first step then  `git log <SHA>^ -- <path-to-file>` works. That is a bit strange.

Comment: Tip: Depending on your use case, you might find it helpful to include `--no-merges` to exclude merge commits.

Answer (score 511):

Get a list of the deleted files and copy the full path of the deleted file

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete
```

Find the commit id of that commit and copy the commit id

```
git log --all -- FILEPATH
```

Show diff of the deleted file

```
git show COMMIT_ID -- FILE_PATH
```

Optionally write output to a file using `>`

```
git show COMMIT_ID -- FILE_PATH > deleted.diff
```

Comment: Although I found the path with help of the first step, the second step throws this error: `unknown revision or path not in the working tree`.

Comment: To see the commit hashes along with the deletes, you can do `git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep -E 'delete|^commit\s+\S+'`

Comment: Step 2 returns nothing. Any ideas of why it may happen? My filename is correct.

Comment: To find combine the three into one function, add this into your .bashrc or .zshrc: `git-grep-latest(){
  result_path=$(git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep $1 | head -1 | awk '{print $4;}');
  latest_commit=$(git log --all -- $result_path | head -1 | awk '{print $2;}');
  git show $latest_commit -- $result_path;
}` and now you can just do: `git-grep-latest some_text`

Comment: `git log --name-only --diff-filter=D --pretty=format: | awk 'NF'` is IMO a cleaner alternative of the first command (to print all now deleted files ever in the repo)

Comment: Or to directly get commit hashes with all files they delete: `git log --name-only --diff-filter=D  --format="%H%b"`

Comment: @TylerJones you can feed anything to anything with linux using pipes - google `linux pipes`.. you'll like that.

Comment: The first command confirmed the file I was looking was deleted, but for some reason when I applied it to the `git log --all -- FILEPATH` command nothing was returned. As an alternative I targetted the file directly and increased the context of the `grep` and got the commit id that way: `git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep -C4 FILEPATH`

Answer (score 118):

Suppose you want to recover a file called `MyFile`, but are uncertain of its path (or its extension, for that matter):

###### 0. (Preliminary) Avoid confusion by stepping to the git root

A nontrivial project may have multiple directories with similar or identical filenames.

```
> cd <project-root>
```

###### 1. Find the full path

```
> git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete | grep MyFile

`delete mode 100644 full/path/to/MyFile.js`
```

`full/path/to/MyFile.js` is the path & file you're seeking.

###### 2. Determine all the commits that affected that file

```
> git log --oneline --follow -- full/path/to/MyFile.js

`bd8374c Some helpful commit message`

`ba8d20e Another prior commit message affecting that file`

`cfea812 The first message for a commit in which that file appeared.`
```

###### 3. Checkout the file

If you choose the first-listed commit (the last chronologically, here bd8374c), the file will not be found, since it was deleted in that commit.

```
> git checkout bd8374c -- full/path/to/MyFile.js

`error: pathspec 'full/path/to/MyFile.js' did not match any file(s) known to git.`
```

Just select the preceding (append a caret) commit:

```
> git checkout bd8374c^ -- full/path/to/MyFile.js
```

Comment: This is a lot more clearer than the accepted answer

Comment: for windows console (cmd), use find instead of grep in step 2:
`git log --diff-filter=D --summary | find "delete" | find "MyFile"`
And step3, note the quotes around the hash:
`git checkout "bd8374c^" -- full/path/to/MyFile.js`

Comment: I'm with @pouyan021 on this one. This answer quickly allowed me to find the commit in which the file was removed.

Comment: Further to @user5542121's suggestion for Windows users, if you're using PowerShell instead of cmd then replace `find` by `Select-String`. So `git log --diff-filter=D --summary | Select-String "delete" | Select-String "MyFile"`

Answer (score 41):

Could not edit the accepted response so adding it as an answer here,

to restore the file in git, use the following (note the '^' sign just after the SHA)

```
git checkout <SHA>^ -- /path/to/file
```

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want the ^. The file is IN the commit with that SHA...why would you want to walk back another commit from there?

Comment: It's in the commit with that sha as "deleted" which means it still won't exist. You have to go to the commit before that to actually get it back.

Comment: @tandrewnichols which just means that you're using the wrong commit SHA - you want the commit for the version of the file you *want*... which probably isn't the version where the file is deleted.

Comment: @Amber and the commit that you want is likely the most recent one before it was deleted, hence this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the ^ tip ^. Beware in windows it needs to be double-quoted.

Comment: @AlexR: `<SHA>~1` should work the same without the need to wrap it with quote marks.

Answer (score 37):

@Amber gave correct answer! Just one more addition, if you do not know the exact path of the file you can use wildcards! This worked for me.

```
git log --all -- **/thefile.*
```

Comment: @PedroMorteRolo Hmm. I don't know how I feel about copying an existing answer into the top-voted one :/ This answer was useful too on its own; an upvote might have been enough?

Comment: This does not find the file if it's in the project root (tested in Cygwin).

Answer (score 25):

Below is a simple command, where a dev or a git user can pass a deleted file name from the repository root directory and get the history:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep filename | awk '{print $4; exit}' | xargs git log --all --
```

If anybody, can improve the command, please do.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Looks like my file never existed at all, but that's a separate and much hairier issue…

Comment: make sure you run this from the repository root directory if your file seems to be 'missing'

Answer (score 19):

Try using one of the viewers, such as `gitk` so that you can browse around the history to find that half remembered file. (use `gitk --all` if needed for all branches)

Comment: That `--all` option is critical for both your answer and the accepted answer.

Comment: Browsing around history will take an extraordinary amount of time for most projects.

Answer (score 14):

#### If you prefer to see the `size` of all deleted file

as well as the associated `SHA`

```bash
git log --all --stat --diff-filter=D --oneline
```

add a `-p|--patch` to see the contents too

```bash
git log --all --stat --diff-filter=D -p
```

To narrow down to any file you have two easy options, you can use a pathspec or you can pipe to grep and search for file name.

Using grep:

```bash
git log --all --stat --diff-filter=D --oneline | grep foo
```

Using a pathspec:

```bash
git log --all --stat --diff-filter=D --oneline -- '*foo*'
```

A pathspec can work well together with `-p|--patch`, if you want to see contents:

```bash
git log --all --stat --diff-filter=D --oneline --patch -- '*foo*'
```

You might also like this one if you know where the file is

```bash
git log --all --full-history -- someFileName
```

Comment: This is the most efficient way I found to locate a commit which deleted a specific file. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Summary:

1. Step 1

You search your file full path in history of deleted files `git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep filename`

2. Step 2

You restore your file from commit before it was deleted

```
restore () {
  filepath="$@"
  last_commit=$(git log --all --full-history -- $filepath | grep commit | head -1 | awk '{print $2; exit}')
  echo "Restoring file from commit before $last_commit"
  git checkout $last_commit^ -- $filepath
}

restore my/file_path
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
git log --all --full-history --oneline -- <RELATIVE_FILE_PATH>
git checkout <COMMIT_SHA>^ -- <RELATIVE_FILE_PATH>
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your question to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen where I didn't even know what the file's name was, so I wanted to see *all* deleted files...

In general, I highly recommend becoming familiar with [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo). It has many uses for re-writing history, but one of its analysis features includes very quickly identifying all deleted files in a repo, and displaying their sizes and date deleted. (Using it on non-Windows OSes is fairly [straight-forward](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md#simple-installation), and [here are installation instructions specifically for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69356543/184546).)

Once you have it runnable in your path, you simply run:

```
git filter-repo --analyze
```

This will output some files in your .git folder, and the one you want to look at for this question is called:

```
.git\filter-repo\analysis\path-deleted-sizes.txt
```

This file shows all deleted files in your repo, reverse sorted by size, and the date it was deleted. Here's an example output:

```
=== Deleted paths by reverse accumulated size ===
Format: unpacked size, packed size, date deleted, path name(s)
    57151421   44898377 2022-07-22 somdirectory/somefileA
    46034619   42929136 2022-01-18 somdirectory/somefileB
    65332368   29102439 2020-09-28 somdirectory/somefileC
    23686432   21681498 2022-07-22 somdirectory/somefileD
    23681272   21678818 2022-07-22 somdirectory/somefileE
    23676153   21670502 2022-07-22 somdirectory/somefileF
    43232768   21439037 2020-07-10 somdirectory/somefileG
    18714315   14299243 2019-01-10 somdirectory/somefileH
    16788104   13035176 2019-01-10 somdirectory/somefileI
```

Obviously you can use this to find the file you're looking for, or, in the context of re-writing history, based on the 2nd column sizes, I know if I remove those 9 deleted files from the history I'll reclaim about 220 MB.

Once you've identified the file you're looking for you can use this to find the commits:

```
git log --all --full-history -- <filename>
```