# How to find and restore one single file from git?

Tags: eclipse, git

I have occasionally delete some file from the project under git control. After that I made many commits. How to (1) find latest revision in the history, where this file contains and (2) restore only it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to locate a deleted file in the commit history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203515/how-to-locate-a-deleted-file-in-the-commit-history)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restore a deleted file in a Git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo)

Comment: How would you identify the file you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

To find the commit that deleted the file:

```
git log --all -- folder/other-folder/file_name.txt
```

or even just

```
git log --all -- */file_name.txt
```

Then just do this:

```
git checkout (commit hash)^ -- folder/other-folder/file_name.txt
```

The ^ tells the git to use not that commit, but one prior.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify which commit the deletion took place in, you can try `git reflog`. `reflog` will show you all the commits that were made to the repository. Once you find the commit, you can do a `git checkout <SHA of commit above>`, that will take your working directory to the state of that commit. You can then copy that version of the file manually, do a `git checkout <branchname>` to go to the required branch and then `commit` the addition of the file in the next `commit`.