# Way to List All Changes on a File in Git

Tags: git

I'm trying to track down who removed some code on a particular file.  I don't know when it was but certainly within the past month.

Is there a way to list history of code changes and details on a specific file via a git command?

**Update**

this didn't work

`git log -p --follow -- src/app/company/index.js`

[image]

**Update**

tried this

`git blame src/app/company/index.js`
fatal: no such path 'src/app/company/index.js' in HEAD

**Update**

ugh, company is capital C...that's what the problem was.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View the change history of a file using Git versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/view-the-change-history-of-a-file-using-git-versioning)

Comment: it's been a file that's been there for a long time in our repo

Comment: Are you running this from the repository root?

Comment: running this from local terminal in WebStorm on my branch

Comment: If the file no longer exists (which you haven't said) then it's a duplicate of this, isn't it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203515/git-how-to-search-for-a-deleted-file-in-the-project-commit-history

Comment: check out the screen cast

Comment: the file DOES exist

Comment: Can you run "ls src/app/company/" please

Comment: `ls src/app/company/index.js`
result: src/app/company/index.js

Comment: if I try this, it errors so the previous command above must work: ls `ls /src/app/company/index.js `
ls: /src/app/company/index.js: No such file or directory

Comment: if I run this, it errors: `git blame src/app/company/index.js`
fatal: no such path 'src/app/company/index.js' in HEAD

Comment: Then the file does not exist on your branch, I suspect your confusion is from the UI not updating in your IDE.

Comment: of course it exists in my branch, we've been working with this file for ages and it's right there in my IDE.  I've been changing code and committing code to this file for a long time now, that's not the issue

Comment: crap I was missing a capital.  The company Directory has a capital C.  All good now

Comment: @PositiveGuy: So, should we delete this as a typo?  Or is there something to say for others with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git log -- path/to/file` to see the commits that modified the file.

It's especially convenient together with the `-p` flag,
to include the diff (patch) that affected the file.

If you want to track the history of a file through renames,
then also add `--follow`.

```
git log -p --follow -- path/to/file
```

Comment: sorry technical difficulties, it's up now

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it might be worth using git blame for this, it shows who made the last edit to each line in the file.

[git blame](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame)

Useage is like this

```
git blame examplefile
```

Answer (score 0):

`git log` accepts file names.  If the file doesn’t exist in the current commit, you have to use `--` before the name to avoid interpreting it as a revision name.