# How can I get the hash of a commit immediately before a faulty commit?

Tags: git, git-log, git-hash

A while back there was a commit that pushed some deletes, a few good, a few not so good.  It is time to restore the deletes that should not have happend.  The following line does come up with a list of all the files that need to be restored:

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only 9168052f32 | grep -v Mobile-Apps-SDK
```

The problem I am running into is that hash is when it was deleted.  My understanding is that to restore the file that was deleted what is needed is the hash BEFORE the delete.

```
git log --follow --pretty=format:"%h" -- config/manifest.json 
9168052
11886af
b6b90ab
```

shows me the list of hashes for one of the files, is there a way to get the second hash, 11886af so that in one long cmd I can restore all the files?

Comment: Do you mean get it programmatically? Based on what criteria? If this is a one-off thing, just do `git checkout <hash> <files>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: How to find a deleted file in the project commit history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203515/git-how-to-find-a-deleted-file-in-the-project-commit-history)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+get+file+previous+commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `9168052f32` commit will have a parent that you can access using `9168052f32^`. That will be the previous commit. If that's the case, you can fish them out from there.