# Git : how to recover a file deleted in old commit?

Tags: git

A few days ago I had the need to recover a file deleted in a prior commit and was unable to find a way to do it. Anyone able to suggest how? Also any of the nice gui git tools provides OOB this capability?

Comment: Had to navigate a few questions but yes it does.
Here is the answer I liked most https://stackoverflow.com/a/7203551/5014665

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout the file from the previous revision from where you deleted it. So, say the revision where it was deleted is rev some-rev:

```
git checkout some-rev~:path-to-file
```

That will leave the file on index ready to be committed.