# Git / How to retrieve the files history after a simple "move files"

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I had the `A` folder containing some files.
I decided to move the content of `A` to `B`, and then trash `B`.

I thought that IntelliJ would be able to do that cleanly regarding Git with the functionality: refactor => Move.

My job working, I decided to commit the whole and synchronize to github with `git push origin master`.

I just notice that my full history regarding the moved files has been dropped......

Is there any way to retrieve them?
What should I have done to move cleanly?

I can see the full history of a specific file like this: 
`git log --follow ./path/to/file`

**but how to attach them naturally**?

The point is that I expect to see them on github.

Comment: *What should I have done to move cleanly?* I don't know about IntelliJ, but at the command line, the right thing to do is `git mv <path-to-A> <path-to-B>`.

Comment: Yes, I've read about this command few hours ago.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lost git history after reorganizing project folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176784/lost-git-history-after-reorganizing-project-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Since Git only stores logical snapshots, there is no reason to worry about how you moved the files. If your GUI cannot figure out that it was moved, that is a shortcoming of the GUI. I find the GUIs to be good at certain tasks, but not good at the more advanced techniques. It is best to have a good feel of how when the GUI can be helpful, but be completely comfortable with command line.

Comment: So you mean that it is a good practice in this case to use the `--follow` option?

Comment: @Mik378 If you are doing lots of moves, yes. It might help to be familiar with -C and -M in the diff and blame commands.