# Lost file history after changing its path and synchronizing with cvs

Tags: java, eclipse, path, synchronization, cvs

I have recently reorganized all java files of my workspace, changing folder and path to most of them. Eclipse, with the "Synchronize with repository" function, seems to delete the file from the old position and then create a copy in the new location, losing all the history related to it.

The question is: is it possible to move files in Eclipse mantaining their cvs history?

My problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176784/lost-git-history-after-reorganizing-project-folder), but it was referred to Git and not useful to me.

I'd really appreciate any help here. Bye!

Comment: CVS is a quite elderly work horse and not really suited for renames, moves - AFAIK. In the original source directory the `.cvs` should contain the "deleted" files.

Comment: Thank you Joop. Exactly, if I move the file back to its original source directory I see again its full history. So the history is referenced to that old path. Does it exixts a way to reference old path to new path?

Comment: After CSV came subversion with the "improvement" to do just that. You might ask in a CSV forum, whether extension, tools or whatever exist to do that. Or otherwise (when no solution crops up) copy the history as text in the first new CSV entry.

Comment: CVS does not maintain the history of moves or renames so if you need this, you are out of luck. This is one of the limitations of CVS that has lead people to move away from it a long time ago.