# Git: renamed file manually, Git confused

Tags: git, version-control

I am using Git and manually renamed a file that I had added to the repository. Now, I have added the "new" file which I renamed to the repository but Git complains that the "old" file has been deleted. So how can I make Git forget about the old file? Better yet, how do I tell Git that the "new" file really is the "new" file so that I can keep the change history intact?

Comment: `git mv old new` is essentially just `git rm --cached old; mv old new; git add new`, with some extra smarts. Git identifies renames by looking for similar content, so it will detect them whether or not you used `git mv`. That is, there's no way to *tell* it that those two files correspond.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make git mark a deleted and a new file as a file move?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433111/how-to-make-git-mark-a-deleted-and-a-new-file-as-a-file-move)

Comment: Weird that almost 8 years has past and git is still not able to detect the rename

Comment: Git rename detection depends on a rename threshold git config setting. If you rename a file and also change the file contents beyond a certain threshold, git will not consider it a rename. Here's a starting point https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---find-renamesltngt

Comment: FWIW, I tried these solutions, but git and github just never understood the renaming I was doing, and I gave up :)

Answer (score 51):

There is no problem. Simply `git rm old` or even `git add -A` and it will realize that it is a rename. Git will see the delete plus the add with same content as a rename.

You don't need to undo, unstage, use `git mv` etc. `git mv old new` is only a short hand for `mv old new; git rm old; git add new`.

Comment: If the old file's already gone, you have to use `git rm --cached old`, since there's no file in the work tree to remove.

Comment: What if you move the file and change a few lines, then `git add -A`? Is Git smart enough to know that a _similar_ file is the same as the old file?

Comment: Moreover, if there are some changes in the body of the files such as different #include statements due to file name change, git still understands this!

Comment: git didn't seem to understand the renamed changed file when I tried - the other answer worked though.

Answer (score 18):

First, cancel your staged add for the manually moved file:

```
$ git reset path/to/newfile
$ mv path/to/newfile path/to/oldfile
```

Then, use Git to move the file:

```
$ git mv path/to/oldfile path/to/newfile
```

Of course, if you already committed the manual move, you may want to reset to the revision before the move instead, and then simply `git mv` from there.

Comment: That last command gave an error: fatal: not under version control

Comment: just had to do: git add oldfile before the last command. THANKS AMBER!

Comment: Just noting that I initially saw `fatal: bad source, source=oldfile destination=newfile`, then realized the instructions in this answer already account for this by renaming the already-renamed file back to the original :)

Comment: @mindthief Sheesh, so it does; thanks. Step 2. `mv path/to/newfile path/to/oldfile`. I noticed if I do this and keep editing the file before committing, and then stage the "changes", I have to `git mv ...` again. Not a big deal though; works great afaict.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mv new old
git rm new
git mv old new
```

Comment: This does not work. Git still does not mark the file as renamed.

Comment: You still need to stage the file with `git add new`

Answer (score 1):

This has to be automated. I never remember git until I commit, and I don't want to.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# This `git rm` wrapper respects the `--cached` option (like `git rm`).

import sys
import subprocess

if "--cached" in sys.argv:
    dest = sys.argv[-1]
    rest = sys.argv[1:-1]
    subprocess.check_call(["git", "add", dest])
    subprocess.check_call(["git", "rm"] + rest)
else:
    subprocess.check_call(["git", "mv"] + sys.argv[1:])
```

I don't want to "remember git mv", because `git mv` adds hidden state behind `git diff` that is *implicitly* added to the next commit, even if you *explicitly* commit something totally unrelated. I know, it's the so called "staged" state, but I don't like it. I like to commit without surprises.

Answer (score -3):

If this error occurs, it probably means that the file you are trying to move is not originally tracked by git or the directory you are trying to move the file into is not a git tracked directory.

Comment: As the OP mentioned, he moved the file which he previously had under version control already. What you describe, is the situation when trying to `git mv` a file, which is not under version control yet (so a file which hasn't been added using `git add` before). Nowadays, the git error message will be very explicit about the file not being checked into vc yet.