# Moved my whole source to another folder, now I can't see previous commits?

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree, file-moving

I had files in the root of the repository with lots of commits.

I decided to **move** the source files to a **new** 'src' folder and leave the root for other kind of files.

In source tree this equaled to **deleting the files in the root** and **creating new files in the 'src' folder**.

Now when I **try to lookup earlier version** of the xyz file, I **can't** because there is only the **'first'** version which is the one which was **created in the 'src' folder**.

Can I attach the *'deleted'* files' commits to the 'new' files?

So When I look at a 'new' file in bitbucket, I can choose which version do I want to see, and I can only see the versions after the move.

**Can I attach the versions of the 'old' file's to the 'new' file?

I hope you understood me :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mercurial or git?

Comment: I use git. ''''

Comment: Did you delete/move the `.git` directory as well?

Comment: Or is your question that when you're looking at the revision history of one of your files inside the `src` directory, it stops at the changeset where you did the move, but you also want to include the history of what you did to the file when it was in the root folder? Is that it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Exactly :)

Comment: Did you change the files when you moved them? Or did you simply move them and then commit? In that case git should've recorded it as a move, but if you also changed the files (enough), then git didn't think the files was really moved. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433111/how-to-make-git-mark-a-deleted-and-a-new-file-as-a-file-move) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I will read it. Btw Source Tree marks it as "Renamed", but bitbucket marks it as a delete & create.

Comment: Then probably the move was recorded properly but Bitbucket simply doesn't handle the metadata that recorded this. In other words, there is probably nothing you can do other than to file an issue with Atlassian.

Comment: Read it, and yeah as I see it detected that I didn't change the contents of the files, but on bitbucket it is marked as a delete & create so there I can't see the older versions of the 'new' file. I will search for it and if Source Tree is capable of this then I will be happy because at least I can use one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will write them.