# How to move a project to another folder by Git in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have solution that looks like this in Visual Studio and I committed them in Git:

```
--project.a
--project.b
```

How should I move them (to for example `srcFolder`) to look like the following without loosing Git history:

```
--srcFolder
  ---project.a
  ---project.b
```

Comment: Are they separate git repos?

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, same repo

Comment: You may move them. You won't lose any history.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to move/rename files in Git and maintain their history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history)

Comment: @evolutionxbox, tnx, i tried "git mv project.a/* srcFolder" but i get fatal:bad source message, actually i was tfs user and not much familiar with git srry if it seems stupid :D

Comment: do you use powershell or cmd?

Comment: @xray i used powershell for git mv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1050326/git-mv-returns-bad-source-in-powershell)

CMD and PowerShell does not expand globing characters, use git bash instead

```
git mv project.a srcFolder
```

should work then.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently "[Git will automatically detect the move/rename if your modification is not too severe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433111/how-to-make-git-mark-a-deleted-and-a-new-file-as-a-file-move#433142)".

Note the very important comment to that answer by `marczych` that if you [first stage the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433111/how-to-make-git-mark-a-deleted-and-a-new-file-as-a-file-move#comment12320303_433142) they will then show up as a move.

(This operation worked fine in Visual Studio 2019.)