# Is there any way to force Git into treating it as a file move? (delete and move)

Tags: git, gitlab

I started by creating a new file, then manually moving it, and then modifying it. It's both a new and removed file, according to Git. Is there a way to make Git handle it like a file transfer?

Comment: Did you create a commit?

Comment: Yes... I did. i was create

Comment: Possible duplicate of How to make git mark a deleted and a new file as a file move?

Comment: Git does not store "moves" nor "copies". You can try playing around witth `-C` and `-M` flags (copy and rename detection). See also [How to make git mark a deleted and a new file as a file move?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433111/how-to-make-git-mark-a-deleted-and-a-new-file-as-a-file-move)